# Why is p modified in numeric lines?

Tags: awk

Take a look at the following code.  My intention was to set the variable `p` only in alphabetic lines.

```
awk '/^[A-Z]/{p="$0"; print "set p: " $p}
{print "p: " $p}' <<EOF
A
1
2
3
B
4
5
6
EOF
```

The program generates the following output on my system:

```
set p: A
p: A
p: 1
p: 2
p: 3
set p: B
p: B
p: 4
p: 5
p: 6
```

Although `p` is set only in alphabetic lines, the values changes in every line. Why?

Comment: Voting to close as a simple typographical error.

Comment: You are mixing up shell and awk syntax. Awk is not shell, it is a completely separate tool with a language of it's own. Read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: @EdMorton, "read the [560 page book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033820.do)" is not a useful answer to a typo.

Comment: @Josh it is THE useful answer to someone who doesn't understand basic awk syntax and so needs to learn it. Providing the definitive source for learning the language (especially when there are so many inferior "resources" out there) is much more useful than correcting every mistake one at a time as they happen through trial-and-error programming and leaving the OP floundering.

Comment: @EdMorton It was not useful and I did not do it. And I will not do it. The only useful suggestion is: **Do not use AWK.**

Comment: @ceving, to be fair, "do not use awk" is also not a useful answer if the job can reasonably be done with awk.

Comment: @ceving you choosing not to do it doesn't make it a useless suggestion. Lots of people ignore good advice every day. If you had followed my advice you would have learned about awk and not come to the ill-informed conclusion that `The only useful suggestion is: Do not use AWK.` which I assume you came to after floundering around trying to guess at its syntax, semantics, and appropriate applications.

Comment: @Josh That is what I have learned from this. CSV is an archaic file format of the 70th and AWK is the tool to work on those files. Both may have a nice place in a museum of computer history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$p` means the field whose number is contained in the variable `p`.  So if `p` is 4, `$p` refers to the fourth field.  I suspect you are mixing up Awk syntax with Perl or shell syntax.

(On my MacOS, I get `awk: illegal field $($0), name "p"` for your example, but this obviously depends on the implementation.)

Notice also the absence of quotes around `$0` in this attempted fix:

```
sierra$ awk '/^[A-Z]/{p=$0; print "set p: " p}
{print "p: " p}' <<<$'A\n1\n2\n3\nB\n4\n5\n6'
set p: A
p: A
p: A
p: A
p: A
set p: B
p: B
p: B
p: B
p: B
```

Answer (score 0):

@try:

```
awk '$0 ~ /[[:alpha:]]/ && val2{print "set p: " val1 ORS val2;val2="";} $0 ~ /[[:alpha:]]/{val1=$0;next} {val2=val2?val2 ORS $0:$0} END{print "set p: " val1 ORS val2}'  Input_file
```

So checking here if line is having alphabets and variable val2 is present then print the values of val1 and val2(val1 will have alphabates value and val2 will have all other values other than alphabets). Now checking if a line is having alphabets in it then set val1 to current line and use next for skipping all next statements. Then if this condition is not satisfied then create variable named val2 whose value will concatenate to itself, in end section block print the value of val1 and val2.

**EDIT:** Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '$0 ~ /[[:alpha:]]/ && val2{
                                print "set p: " val1 ORS val2;
                                val2="";
                               }
     $0 ~ /[[:alpha:]]/{
                        val1=$0;
                        next
                       }
                       {
                        val2=val2?val2 ORS $0:$0
                       }
     END{
                print "set p: " val1 ORS val2
        }
    '  Input_file
```

Comment: This seems quite complicated, if I compare it to the removal of two dollar signs. ;-)

Comment: actually speaking I didn't understand why OP wanted to use $p's value in his/her coding, so what I understood from output is OP wants to get the value of line starting with alphabets and then print the all values into next. So I have written these conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$ cat f
A
1
2
3
B
4
5
6
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i ~ /[[:alpha:]]/) {k=$i;print "set p: "k} {print "p: " k}}' f
set p: A
p: A
p: A
p: A
p: A
set p: B
p: B
p: B
p: B
p: B
```